# How to watching a packet?

Tags: sockets, packet

I will send a TCP SYN Packet from my PC to server, some time my packet lost and i nerver know why! Ext:

```
PACKET        LAN                ROUTER               INTERNET               HOST        
TCP Syn   ->  192.168.1.5   ->   192.168.1.1    ->    ISP Of internet   ->   156.5.5.5
OK        ->  OK            ->   Maybe die      ->    Maybe lost        ->   Lost
```

So i need some software or solutions can wathching packet come to router and from router come to internet, if packet send failed i can know packet how to fail!

P/S: Not wireshark because wireshark only capture packet out or in, not wathching or tracert packet. If wireshark can wathching a packet please teach me.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Wireshark can capture any packet in Promiscuous mode or Monitor mode. but, do you want to see the packets that the router gets from the internet or from the local network?

Comment: @MeNa I want see packet go to the router and in router success send to internet. In the local network packet never lost

Comment: So unplug the router and connect your PC directly to the internet. then wireshark can view everything sent/comes the internet.

Comment: @MeNa thanks i will find another solutions for this problem! May be i will using DD-WRT router for all control packet :(

Comment: As you wish dude, but why so complicated?! just connect your PC to "the hole in the wall" and so you can capture anything.

Comment: @MeNa i want send spoofing IP adress from my PC to internet, i will creat TCP Syn packet with spoofing ip but maybe router drop my packet or some reason then i need buy cisco router and using command line for dump all packet or edit firmware for send spoofing ipaddress.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41601/discussion-between-mena-and-vietnguyen09)